# How to instantiate a class based on web.config file with Castle Windsor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, castle-windsor

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC application and I would like to instantiate a class based on settings written in web.config.

```
<configSections>
    <section name="castle"
        type="Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AppDomain.CastleSectionHandler, Castle.Windsor" />
</configSections>

<castle>
    <components>
        <component
            id="SqlRepository"
            service="GomokuGameAppDomain.IGameRepository, GomokuGameAppDomain"
            type="GomokuGameAppDomain.SqlGameRepository, GomokuGameAppDomain"
            lifestyle="PerWebRequest">
            <parameters>
                 <connectionString>Data Source=ZOLIQ-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Gomoku;Integrated Security=True</connectionString>
            </parameters>
    </component>
</castle>
...
```

I would like to use something like this:

```
var container =
    new WindsorContainer (new XmlInterpreter (new ConfigResource ("castle")));

gameRepository = container.Resolve (typeof (IGameRepository)) as IGameRepository;
```

How could I resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for the sake of completeness, the whole code looks like this:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Install(Castle.Windsor.Installer.Configuration.FromAppConfig());
var gameRepository = container.Resolve<IGameRepository>();
```

Happy coding.

Comment: why not `var gameRepository = container.Resolve<IGameRepository>();` ? Simpler, nicer...
`

Answer (score 3):

```
container.Install(Configuration.FromAppConfig());
```